# Creating a tic tac toe board through the use of a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

In this code, I try to create a two dimensional array that represents a tic tac toe board (with user input) but no matter what I enter in "TicTacLine", the program always brings up "Have you never played Tic Tac Toe before ? It's okay if you haven't, but just FYI, it plays with x's and o's.", which is the message I wrote if the characters in uno, dos and tres weren't either x's or o's.

```
public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int TicTac[][]= new int[3][3];

        System.out.println("Enter the Tic Tac Toe board you want to see, one line at a time.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String TicTacLine = scanner.nextLine();     
        int loop = 0;

        if (TicTacLine.length()<3 | TicTacLine.length()>3) {  // I try to define the array by a series of inputs that go in the while loop.
            System.out.println("Tic-tac-toe plays in a 3×3 grid. This means if you want to input a line, you would want to input 3 characters, no more, no less.");
        } else { 
            while (loop != 3) { // we count the loops so that there's only 3 different lines
                char uno = TicTacLine.charAt(0);
                char dos = TicTacLine.charAt(1);
                char tres = TicTacLine.charAt(2);
                if (uno != 'x' | uno != 'o' | dos != 'x' | dos != 'o' | tres != 'x' | tres != 'o') {
                    System.out.println("Have you never played Tic Tac Toe before ? It's okay if you haven't, but just FYI, it plays with x's and o's.");
                    break;
                } else { 
                    if (loop == 0) {
                        TicTac[0][0] = uno;
                        TicTac[0][1] = dos;
                        TicTac[0][2] = tres; 
                        loop = ++loop;
                        TicTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
                    } if (loop == 1) {
                        TicTac[1][0] = uno;
                        TicTac[1][1] = dos;
                        TicTac[1][2] = tres;
                        loop = ++loop;
                        TicTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
                    } if (loop == 2) {
                        TicTac[2][0] = uno;
                        TicTac[2][1] = dos;
                        TicTac[2][2] = tres;
                        loop = ++loop;
                        TicTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        if (loop == 3) {
        for(int[] row : TicTac) {
            PrintingRow(row);
            } 
          } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you use .equals instead of == to compare strings. Also, you are using | instead of || for "or". Also, in the line, "TicTacLine.length()<3 | TicTacLine.length()>3" you can use "TicTacLine.length() != 3" instead. Also, just a convention in java that you should be using: You named a variable "TicTacLine" in java, we use lowerCamelCase so it should be renamed to: "ticTacLine" Your class name, "TicTacToe" is fine and class names use PascalCase. EDIT: You are comparing chars the right way. I thought those were strings for a second.

Comment: Think about it: what value of `uno` would make `uno != 'x' | uno != 'o'` be `false`? It needs to be `&&`.

Comment: I did change the name of my variable and ticTacLine.length() != 3 but it doesn't make the error message disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boolean expression within the `IF` statement will always be true:

```
if (uno != 'x' | uno != 'o' | dos != 'x' | dos != 'o' | tres != 'x' | tres != 'o')
```

Why?
Because you are ORing the result of all six subexpressions together. Since it is the case that at least three of these will always be true, and possibly all six are true, then the whole expression will ***always*** be true.

Look at the first two boolean expressions that you are bitwise ORing together. This returns true always because either `uno != 'x'` is true, or `uno != 'o'` is true, or both, so the expression will always be true, so you will always execute the

```
System.out.println("Have you never played Tic Tac Toe before ? It's okay if you haven't, but just FYI, it plays with x's and o's.");
break;
```

You need to rewrite this using *logical* ORs and ANDs as follows:

```
if ((uno != 'x' && uno != 'o') || (dos != 'x' && dos != 'o') || (tres != 'x' && tres != 'o')) {
```

This says, evaluate to `true` if `uno is not 'x' and uno is not 'o'`, `or` evaluate to true `if dos is not 'x' and dos is not 'o'`, `or` evaluate to true if `tres is not 'x' and tres is not 'o'`

For more information on Java Operators, Oracle has good documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Some general things:

First of all you should not do

```
loop = ++loop;
```

If you want to increment `loop` just code

```
++loop;
```

Second instead of doing all this `if else (loop == ...)` stuff you can do

```
TicTac[loop][0] = uno;
TicTac[loop][1] = dos;
TicTac[loop][2] = tres;
++loop;
ticTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
```

only once.

And last if you know the number of loops it is much easier and better to read when you use a for loop instead of a while loop.

Now to the program itself.

The

```
ticTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
```

is not required because you are doing

```
String ticTacLine = scanner.nextLine();
```

at each begin of the loop. Currently you are reading the input twice with every loop.

And the printing should be outside of the loop. Then you also don't need to check for the loop value but just call it once.

What you read from the inout is characters, but what you put into the array is the int value of the character. If you want to store characters you have to use a character array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't infortunately solve the problems that I have with the numbers of inputs, the error message that doesn't always bring up and the board that displays numbers.

Comment: I wrote my answer in two steps. Please check again. One thought that came into my mind after I posted my answer is that you should try to debug the code. This would have been very helpful to find out the problems with the two scans and the char to int casting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to give you an important piecoe of advice when it comes to structuring with conditional statements. Try to minimize your code ina n if or else statement

Secondly heres the error

```
 if (uno != 'x' | uno != 'o' | dos != 'x' | dos != 'o' | tres != 'x' | tres != 'o')
```

You see you use the | operator for a boolean statement. You apparently confused the bitwise operator | and the logical operator || (or)

It's very important to know the the difference. You see the bitwise operator basically takes two binary numbers 
like

```
1001 | 1010 = 1011
```

because its like the logical operator but for 1 and zero. 
Attention: Theres also the bitwise AND operator that looks like &
but its not the logical &&

Comment: While the use of bitwise operators is an error in this case as you point out, the root cause of the error is that the expression always evaluates to true because it is always true that uno is either not an 'x' or not an 'o'. The code should only evaluate to true if both conditions hold, so a logical AND is required between these two (and also in the other test for the other two characters).

Comment: Thanks for the comment I saw the operator and I just assumed it was the source of the error. I appreciate your explanation and hope i can learn from this.